# How to make a video using Intent?

Tags: java, android

There is the following code for starting video recording using Intent:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), 100);
```

But there is some problem: it works good on my device, i.e. I recorded some video, then clicked by "complete" button in standard video recorder and all was good. But if user used device with Android less then 4.0 his device might have no "complete" button, therefore user could record, but couldn't save this new video and my onActivityResult() method got null in data field of Intent. Please, tell me, is there any universal way to start Intent for record video using Intent?

Comment: I don't understand why

Comment: Did you try it on several pre 4.0 devices? I could be just a bug in implementation of video recording application for this device.